# How to parse class in one style BeautifulSoup4 python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html:

```
<tr style="height: 45px"><td class="s32" dir="ltr">100</td></tr>
<tr style="height: 35px"><td class="s32" dir="ltr">1000</td></tr>
```

I need to parse `'s32' class` only in `'height: 45px' style` but programm parse all `'s32' class`

I recently start use bs4 and I still don't understand how to parse something in one style, can someone explain me that, please?

Now, I have that code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

url = ''
r = requests.get(url)
soup = b(r.text, 'html.parser')
output = soup.find_all('td', class_='s32')
clear_output = [c.text for c in output]
print(clear_output)
```

Output:

```
['100', '1000']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `style` is on the parent, you'll need to `find_all` `td`, then check if the `.parent['style']` includes something like `height: 45px`, if so, add to a list:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <tr style="height: 45px"><td class="s32" dir="ltr">100</td></tr>
    <tr style="height: 35px"><td class="s32" dir="ltr">1000</td></tr>
"""

result = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tds = soup.find_all('td', class_='s32')

for td in tds:
    if 'height: 45px' in td.parent['style']:
        result.append(td.getText())

print(result)
```

Will output:

```
['100']
```